# Unexpected page scroll when element loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, widget, element

I am loading an embeddable element, but when the page loads it jumps/scrolls to the element. I've tried adding in a function that would scroll to the top of the page using jQuery, but to no avail.

I've noticed this behaviour on Chrome and Edge, however, it does not occur on FireFox. Any clues?

I expected the page to not scroll to the element. I added the jQuery function and still experience the same behaviour.

```js
const elementConfig = {
  language: 'en-US',
  trip: {
    originAirport: "RIX",
    destinationAirport: "TLL"
  },
  placement: '',
  features: {
    showFilters: true,
    showMapLegend: true,
  }
}

function onSherpaEvent(event) {
  // Ensure that the sdk is loaded before creating the element:
  if (event.type === 'sdkLoaded') {
    $sherpa.V2.createElement('map', elementConfig).mount('#sherpa-trip-element');

  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://sdk-sandbox.joinsherpa.io/widget.js?appId=sxM5NjIzNz" defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="what">What</div> <br> some <br> content <br> that <br> is <br> just <br> meant <br> to <br> be <br> a <br> placeholder <br> in order <br> to see <br> if <br> this <br> scroll <br> issue <br> happens <br> here
<div id="sherpa-trip-element">sherpa-trip-element</div>
```

Comment: I clicked [edit], then the snippet editor `[<>]` and pasted your HTML and JS into the panes. Clicked TIDY and saved. I cannot see the issue and there are console warnings. Please make sure you post a [mcve]

Comment: thank you @mplungjan I tried what you recommended but it says you already edited the post?

Comment: Yes. I did it for you to stop others from downvoting your question. It was a mess :)

Comment: I still cannot see what your problem is. Can you make the snippet show the problem? it is likely that $sherpa wants to focus itself

Comment: @mplungjan I recreated it here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-fcdbzp?file=index.html

You will notice once the element finishes loading it jumps to the sherpa element when I want it to stay at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask Sherpa. There are hundreds of scroll calls in the widget. There is no callback on mount and the document.ready is already triggered when the sherpa focuses.

The best bet is to move the widget into an iFrame you control